# Alternative for Adobe Dreamweaver with drag and drop design

Tags: adobe, dreamweaver, html-editor

Is there any such a great html editor with drag and drop design interface which is equivalent to Adobe Dreamweaver.

I googled so many such as Komodo, Aptana, Coffee Cup.Of course, those are good html editors but they do not have design interface where we can drag and drop html elements and align them(What we can do by Dreamweaver).

Can you please suggest me if there is any such great tool for Windows OS.

Thanks in advance.....

**Note:** This question may be duplicate one.But I have seen already some of the relevant questions in StackOverflow but no question has been answered as what I want actually.So that I posted again..*So please dont mark it as duplicate*

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Expression Web](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Web_Overview.aspx) is what I feel is the only suitable alternate to dreamweaver. It has nearly all the features of dreamweaver.